# sudo: unable to open … Read-only file system on proxmox server

Tags: 14.04, server, debian

I am running into a strange problem with my dedicated server. I Installed proxmox VE (KVM hypervisor system hosted on Debian) on the server, every few days the system goes to the mode. I also have four VPSs on the host server ubuntu 14.04 is installed on these four VPSs. they all goes to the same mode when this problem happens.

```
> sudo: unable to open … Read-only file system
```

After I reboot the system it worked well few more days and then ran to the same problem again. Do you have any idea about how to fix it? or what could it be behind this problem?

Comment: I have four VMs with ubuntu 14.04 hosted on the server, all these VMs goes to same mode (read only file system)

Comment: all my VMs has ubuntu 14.04 OS installefd on it. and host servers has debian

Comment: @DavidFoerster [Proxmox VE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxmox_Virtual_Environment) is a virtualization environment or hypervisor system. Installed on a physical machine, it allows you to run multiple virtual machines or containers. According to the OP, the host runs Debian, the VMs are based on KVM and use Ubuntu. The filesystem of each VM resides in a directory on the host system (at least, it does when running OpenVZ container on Proxmox VE, I'd assume it's the same when running KVM VMs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix “sudo: unable to open … Read-only file system”?](/q/197459/175814)

Answer (score 2):

The filesystem will usually go into read-only while the system is running if there is a filesystem consistency issue. This is specified in `fstab` as `errors=remount-ro` and will occur when a FS access fails or an emergency read-only remount is requested via `Alt`+`SysRq`+`U`. You can run:

> `sudo fsck -Af -M`

to force a check of all filesystems. As one of the other answers states, looking at `dmesg` is also very helpful.

Comment: running sudo fsck -Af -M
gives me the following:
root@server-BigData:~# fsck -Af -M
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2

but now my server is working well after I rebooted. I mean how exactly I can avoid happening this again?

Comment: @NashvanMustafa: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) or edit your question if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.